# Xcode 4.6, Why does it show assembler although "Show Disassembly When Debugging" is unchecked

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using XCODE4.6,  "Show Disassembly When Debugging" is unchecked. 
But it is still showing assembler to me sometimes.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That option is for displaying the assembler of your compiled code (see the [guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/060-Debug_and_Tune_Your_App/debug_app)).  The reason you are seeing some assembler is that you are stepping into library code for which there is no source available.

Comment: Thanks. I see. I'm new. Just found the reason after add some log in source code